# XSLT copy-of not retaining whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt

While transforming the following xml using xsl:copy-of - my transformation looses the formatting of the origianl document - I dont want it to touch the original at all. Litrally just copy the node - untouched

Source XML

```
  <flow>
    <flow>
      <material><mattext fontface="Arial"><p style="white-space: pre-wrap"><font size="11">The moon is the only extraterrestrial body to be visited by humans?</font></p></mattext>
</material>
    </flow>
```

I get this result

```
<flow><flow><material><mattext fontface="Arial" texttype="text/plain"><p style="white-space: pre-wrap"><font size="11">The moon is the only extraterrestrial body to be visited by humans?</font></p></mattext></material></flow>
```

As you can see its put it all on one line - for my purpose I need to retain the whitespace (pretty print is not an option)

My XSL looks like this

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="qti:item" group-adjacent="(position()-1)">

<!-- Output the file-->
<xsl:result-document  href="{$filename}">
<questtag>
<!-- Output the contents-->
<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
</questtag>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Update: Ok - I found that if I remove the source files DTD then the whitespace is retained - but this isnt an option for the solution

Comment: Rob, consider to present minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem, as well as information about which XSLT 2.0 processor and which XML parser you use. I am afraid the posted source XML does not show any `qti:item` at all which your `for-each-group` processes.

Comment: ...how do you apply the XSLT? If you load the XML first in a DOM object - or go through a DOM object to save the result -  that could result in loosing the whitespaces, regardless of what the XSLT is doing

Comment: I use SAXON 9.4 to transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 states that when the source is constructed from a DTD- or schema-validated document, whitespace in element-only content is ignored/stripped before it reaches the XSLT processor. So there is no whitespace by the time XSLT sees it. If you want whitespace to be significant, you need to declare the content model as mixed content.

Comment: I think thats exactly what happened! But adding the -strip:none to my SAXON command line (even though none is the default) seamed to fix the issue